I have a granite tread on top step of stoop. I want to cut a slot in it to allow water to drain off patio,
top step is higher slightly than cement patio. Will a 'V' shaped slot protect step from cracking when water freezes in there, Slot will be about 1/4 inch deep running from front to back of step.

This one's gonna need pictures. Please take enough so we can see what you're seeing, and use the Edit link & Mountain icon to add them in.

Standing freezing water can cause problems.  A V or U shape might slow it down enough till after you move.  Raising the patio or lowing the step would probably be the better answer.  Slightly higher might be able to grind down flat enough to be lower.
